# In what cases is SOR method faster than Jacobi and Gauss-seidel

Tags: linear-algebra

My book says that if a matrix is diagonally dominant or irreducible, then both Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel converge, and Gauss-Seidel method is asymptotically not slower than Jacobi.

It also speaks about SOR method, saying that it's generally faster than Jacobi and Gauss-Seidel, but it doesn't say when. So is there a method used to determine what of these 3 methods is faster?